# Trying to save an SQLite database from command line but it's not giving *.sqlite nor *.db, just saves a filename without any extension

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, ormlite

So I go into directory with `sqlite3.exe` and open it with double click then I type in the following commands (I'm including foreign keys pragma as I will need it in the future):

```
PRAGMA FOREIGN_KEYS=ON;

CREATE TABLE `countries` (
    `country_id`    INTEGER NOT NULL,
    `name`  TEXT NOT NULL UNIQUE,
     PRIMARY KEY(country_id)
);

INSERT INTO `countries` VALUES 
 (1,'Japan'),
 (2,'China');

.save countries
```

This gives me a file with no extension type, only: `countries`

But all the tutorials I see for opening a pre-made/existing database in **android** they use to open file with extensions such as `example.db` or `example.sqlite`

What am I missing?  When I try to open this file with ORMlite I get:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Problems executing runExecute Android statement: 
   CREATE TABLE `countries` (`name` VARCHAR ,
       `country_id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT )
```

Comment: File extensions are conventions; they don't affect the file's data. Just rename `countries` to `countries.db` or whatever you prefer. You're likely getting that error because ORMlite is attempting to create the table that you already created.

Comment: You told it to save to a file named `countries` and it saved to a file named `countries`. Just like you told it to.